# How to include nunit test results in sonarcube 4.5.1 c# plugin 3.3 sonar-project.properties file?

Tags: c#, nunit, sonarqube

I see that sonarcube re-added nunit test results support since Nov 7 2014:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Plugin

However, I did not find anything that showed how to do this in the sonar-project.properties file.

For example, see the one they provide on git hub here:
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/projects/languages/csharp/sonar-project.properties

What nunit specific line should be put in this file to replace the "sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=TestResults/*.trx" mstest line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newly added key for NUnit test reports can be found on the project c# settings page - under UNit Tests tab, and its value is:

```
sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths
```

Provided value should be the .xml output from the NUnit console runner.

Comment: This worked (e.g. something like sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=UnitTestResults/*.results.xml).  Thanks!

Comment: this is not working any longer... i tried to set it to reportsPath, but it is not finding the xml

Comment: @entre can  you verify that the xml file is available (e.g. the tests are executed and the report is generated). My report file is in the same root folder as the sonar-project.properties file and is working ok.